# Node.js + Redis, What is the correct way to transactionally change a key according to its previous value using node.js

Tags: node.js, redis, transactions, watch

Using Node.js + Redis, I'm trying to transactionally change the value of a key relying on its previous value. However setting the new value occurs before i update the  **prevValue** variable, resulting with the same value it had before.

```
redisClient.watch("a",(err,result)=> {
    var prevValue
    redisClient.multi()
    .get('a',(err,result)=>{
        console.log('get ',err,result)
        prevValue = result 
    })
    .set('a' ,prevValue + "*" ,(err,result)=> {
        console.log('set ',err,result)
    })
    .exec((err,result)=> {
        console.log('exec ',err,result) 
    })
 })
```

Comment: Remove the get call from the multi block. Put it after the watch call, but before the multi call.

Comment: Another option is to use a Lua script to do the whole thing server side atomically.

Comment: Works. Thanks!
Will also check the Lua solution.